# Is there a maxlength on Vim's runtimepath, if so how can I raise it?

Tags: vim

I have added a lot of bundles via vundle and the `runtimepath` seems to be cut off after 1024 characters.

I display the path via `set runtimepath` and it prints out a string which seems to be cut off after 1024 characters.

I'll just show the end of the `runtimepath` for brevity.

```
~/.vim/bundle/nginx-vim-syntax,~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips,~/.vim/bundle/ultisnip-snippets,~/.vim,/usr
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This limit is hardcoded. Do you *really* need that many plugins? Vim can do a lot by itself.

Comment: So the plugins don't load anymore? I'm using GVim 7.3 with Vundle and `echo len(&runtimepath)` gives 2770.

Comment: I managed to get the plugin to work, it was a user error on my part (not reading UltiSnips documentation carefully enough to know how to add my own snippet directory properly.) The problem seems to be outputting the runtimepath and not the actual loading from it.

Comment: @romainl I'm aware that Vim can do a lot by itself, but I like the clean separation I get with vundle. This means I have a separate bundle for simple things like `nginx-vim-syntax`. Very easy to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is from [`:help options`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%24HOME):

```
Note the maximum length of an expanded option is limited.  How much depends on
the system, mostly it is something like 256 or 1024 characters.
```

I don't believe it's possible to change this maximum. However, if you execute `:echo &rtp`, the entire value is printed, so the limit seems to apply only to `:set rtp`.

Comment: Thanks, it works to output `:echo &rtp` as suggested. `echo len(&runtimepath)` as suggested by @Daan also works well.